# MongoDB Compass analyze schema and show map using object and not array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

I'm using MongoDB Compass v1.26 and I have some collections with lat/long data, but they looks like this:

```
"coordinates": {
    "latitude": "43.0818",
    "longitude": "-87.892"
}
```

It does not pick it up in the schema > analyze to show as a map. I think it needs to be an array.

However, using the tool, I can only filter, project, sort, etc. So, I can't run a query to `{ $objectToArray: <object> }` other than storing a converted copy of the entire collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your field contains [GeoJSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/geojson/#geojson-objects) data or `[longitude,latitude]` arrays, the Schema tab displays a map containing the points from the field. The data type for location fields is coordinates.

MongoDB supports the GeoJSON object types.

To specify GeoJSON data, use an embedded document with:

- a field named `type` that specifies the GeoJSON object type and
- a field named `coordinates` that specifies the object's coordinates.

If specifying latitude and longitude coordinates, list the `longitude` first and then `latitude`:

```
coordinates: [<longitude>, <latitude>]
```

or

```
<field>: { type: <GeoJSON type> , coordinates: [<longitude>, <latitude>] }
```

You can try below projection in PROJECT part,

- `$toDouble` to convert string to double type
- pass both long and lat as per first syntax in array

```
{ coordinates: [{ $toDouble:"$coordinates.longitude"}, {$toDouble:"$coordinates.latitude"}] }
```

Comment: works like a charm thanks. note that i had to filter out `$exists: true` to get it to draw.